# Friend specific template instantiation of operator

Tags: c++, friend

I have a class template and an operator template that needs to access its private field. I can make a template friend:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    int x;
    template <typename U>
    friend bool operator==(const A<U>& a, const A<U>& b);
};

template <typename T>
bool operator== (const A<T>& a, const A<T>& b) {
    return a.x == b.x;
}

int main() {
    A<int> x, y;
    x == y;
    return 0;
}
```

But is it possible to make only `operator==<T>` friend for `A<T>` and not making `operator==<int>` friend of `A<double>` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If having trouble with `friend`, then bring the declaration forward, before the `A` class is defined.

```
template <typename T>
bool operator== (const A<T>& a, const A<T>& b);
```

Then you can `friend` it more clearly. Full solution ([ideone](http://ideone.com/a0aIaa)):

```
template <typename T>
class A;

// declare operator== early (requires that A be introduced above)
template <typename T>
bool operator== (const A<T>& a, const A<T>& b);

// define A
template <typename T>
class A { 
    int x;
    // friend the <T> instantiation
    friend bool operator==<T>(const A<T>& a, const A<T>& b);
};

// define operator==
template <typename T>
bool operator== (const A<T>& a, const A<T>& b) { 
    return a.x == b.x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. The syntax is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    int x;
    friend bool operator==<>(const A& a, const A& b);
};
```

And put your `operator==` definition(or just a declaration) before the `A` class.

Comment: This isn't a compiler bug. There are places where that syntax is valid, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @AlanStokes, well, yes this syntax is completely valid here. Why don't you try yourself? Just put `operator==` before the class.

Comment: It's valid if there's a previous declaration of `operator==` as a template, which isn't in your answer.

Comment: But it's hardly a bug, considering g++, clang and MSVC all reject the first code

Comment: Only a declaration is needed before, not the definition.

Comment: @ixSci Sounds like a compiler bug ;-)

Comment: @ixSci, sorry, I am not able to check you claim easily because I don't have thos compiler. tried MSVC compiler here (not sure which version) http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual

Comment: You're neither declaring a template nor referring to an existing template.

Comment: @AlanStokes, thank you. You are right, somehow I missed that out.

Comment: @RiaD, I've also tried different online compilers(including the one MS provides with the latest unreleased build) and all of them reject this code. Strange. My local MSVC2015 Update 2 compiles it fine.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯